# Value error when trying to create a new dataframe column with a function

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am running into a value error when trying to create a new column in my dataframe. It looks like this:

```
      state  veteran_pop  pct_gulf  pct_vietnam
0    Alaska        70458      20.0         31.2
1   Arizona       532634       8.8         15.8
2  Colorado       395350      10.1         20.8
3   Georgia       693809      10.8         21.8
4      Iowa       234659       7.1         13.7
```

So I have a function that looks like this:

```
def addProportions(table, col1, col2, new_col):

    for row, index in table.iterrows():
        table[new_col] = ((table[col1] + table[col2])/100)
    return(table)
```

Where `table` is the table above and `col1 = "pct_gulf"`, `col2 = "pct_vietnam"`, and `new_col = "pct_total"` like so:

```
addProportions(table, "pct_gulf", "pct_vietnam", "total_pct")
```

But when I run this function I get this error message:

`ValueError: Wrong number of items passed 2, placement implies 1`

--- Alternatively---

I have made my `addProportions` function like this:

```
def addProportions(table, col1, col2, new_col):
    table[new_col] = 0
    for row, index in table.iterrows():
        table[new_col] = ((table[col1] + table[col2])/100)
    return(table)
```

And I get this output, which seems like a step in the right direction.

```
      state veteran_pop pct_gulf pct_vietnam total_pct
0    Alaska       70458     20.0        31.2       NaN
1   Arizona      532634      8.8        15.8       NaN
2  Colorado      395350     10.1        20.8       NaN
3   Georgia      693809     10.8        21.8       NaN
4      Iowa      234659      7.1        13.7       NaN
```

But the problem is when I use `type()` on the two columns I try to add it comes up as a dataframe and that's why I think I'm getting NaN.

---- Table Info ----

`t.info()`

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 55 entries, 0 to 54
Data columns (total 4 columns):
(state,)          55 non-null object
(veteran_pop,)    55 non-null int64
(pct_gulf,)       55 non-null float64
(pct_vietnam,)    55 non-null float64
dtypes: float64(2), int64(1), object(1)
memory usage: 1.8+ KB
```

`t.index`

`RangeIndex(start=0, stop=55, step=1)`

`t.columns`

`MultiIndex(levels=[[u'pct_gulf', u'pct_vietnam', u'state', u'veteran_pop']],
           codes=[[2, 3, 0, 1]])`

Comment: please post the data as copyable text

Comment: @anky_91 There you go

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a loop. You only need (table is the name of your dataframe):

```
table.columns=table.columns.droplevel()
table['total_pct']=(table['pct_gulf']+table['pct_vietnam'])/100
print(table)
```

Comment: are you sure? There shouldn't be any errors, I don't get any errors with your data frame. If both series have the same index and are not str type, you should not have problems

Comment: run this code separately and do not take any further action

Comment: I'm absolutely sure. But I don't get that error when I first create the column like in the alternative case above. Instead I get a bunch of NaN values where the addition should have worked.

Comment: Use Copy and paste your dataframe post in your answer. Then use `table=pd.read_clipboard()` and then my code `table['total_pct']=(table['pct_gulf']+table['pct_vietnam'])/100
`...you will not obtain any error

Comment: that worked and now I am wondering if there is something wrong with the dataframe I am trying to modify.

Comment: post `table.info()` , `table.index` and `table.columns` in your answer. Try: `table.reset_index(drop=True)` before

Comment: posted that output in the Table Info section above.

Comment: the problem may be the mutlindex of the columns ...try : `table.columns=table.columns.droplevel()` and then use my code. If it works consider accept my answer

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you have a MultiIndex.

My DataFrame, when I construct one from your info, looks like this:

```
    table = pd.DataFrame(data={"state":["Alaska", "Arizona", "Colorado", 
    "Georgia", "Iowa"], 

    "veteran_pop":[70458, 532634, 395350, 693809, 234659],

    "pct_gulf": [20.0, 8.8, 10.1, 10.8, 7.1],

    "pct_vietnam": [31.2, 15.8, 20.8, 21.8, 13.7]})
```

And table.info() shows this:

```
    <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
    RangeIndex: 5 entries, 0 to 4
    Data columns (total 5 columns):
    state          5 non-null object
    veteran_pop    5 non-null int64
    pct_gulf       5 non-null float64
    pct_vietnam    5 non-null float64
    total_pct      5 non-null float64
    dtypes: float64(3), int64(1), object(1)
    memory usage: 280.0+ bytes
```

If I construct a MultiIndex, I get an error:

```
    multi = pd.DataFrame(data={("state",):["Alaska", "Arizona", "Colorado", "Georgia", "Iowa"], 

    ("veteran_pop",):[70458, 532634, 395350, 693809, 234659],

    ("pct_gulf",): [20.0, 8.8, 10.1, 10.8, 7.1],

    ("pct_vietnam",): [31.2, 15.8, 20.8, 21.8, 13.7]})
```

If I run addProportions(table) on my regular DataFrame, I get the right answer:

```
    state        veteran_pop    pct_gulf    pct_vietnam total_pct
     0  Alaska    70458         20.0        31.2        0.512
    1   Arizona   532634        8.8         15.8        0.246
    2   Colorado  395350        10.1        20.8        0.309
    3   Georgia   693809        10.8        21.8        0.326
    4   Iowa      234659        7.1         13.7        0.208
```

but running it on the MultiIndex throws an error.

```
    TypeError: addProportions() missing 3 required positional arguments: 
    'col1', 'col2', and 'new_col'
```

Somehow, you ended up with a MultiIndex in your columns, even though you don't have hierarchical categories here. (You'd only want it if you were breaking down percentages, for example, by year:

```
    columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([["percentage","veteran_pop"], ["army","navy"], ["2010", "2015"]])
    pd.DataFrame( columns=columns, index=pd.RangeIndex(start=0, stop=5))

    percentage  veteran_pop
    army    navy    army    navy
    2010    2015    2010    2015    2010    2015    2010    2015
    0   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
    1   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
    ...
```

You'll need to reshape your DataFrame to use the function you've written. The function works, but you have the wrong kind of index in your columns.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep the data as multi-index, change the function to:

```
def addProportions(table, col1, col2, new_col):

    table[new_col] = ((table[(col1,)] + table[(col2,)])/100)
    # you can enable the return line if it is in need
    # return table
```

If you want to reshape the data into normal data:

```
def addProportions(table, col1, col2, new_col):

    table[new_col] = ((table[col1] + table[col2])/100)
    # you can enable the return line if it is in need
    # return table

# shape a new df without the multi-index 
new_col = [i[0] for i in multi.columns]
new_df = pd.DataFrame(multi.values, columns = new_col)

# call funtion
addProportions(new_df, "pct_gulf", "pct_vietnam", "total_pct")
```

Comment: I am going to try out this solution later this week and see if it works. I think I am somehow multi-indexing when I am creating my new table.